# android - how to validate drawing

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, paint, touch-event

In my app, the customer has to sign at the end of the process. Below code is how I manage to make it work.

DrawView

```
public class DrawView 
extends View {

    private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;

    /** Need to track this so the dirty region can accommodate the stroke. **/
    private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    /** Optimizes painting by invalidating the smallest possible area. */
    private float lastTouchX;
    private float lastTouchY;
    private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    }

    /** Erases the signature. */
    public void clear() {
        path.reset();

        // Repaints the entire view.
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            lastTouchX = eventX;
            lastTouchY = eventY;
            // There is no end point yet, so don't waste cycles invalidating.
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // Start tracking the dirty region.
            resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);

            // When the hardware tracks events faster than they are delivered,
            // the
            // event will contain a history of those skipped points.
            int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
            //Logger.debug("historySize : " + historySize);
            for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
                float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
                path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
            }
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);

            break;

        default:
            //Logger.debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }

        // Include half the stroke width to avoid clipping.
        invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH), (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH), (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH), (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;

        return true;
    }

    /** Called when replaying history to ensure the dirty region includes all
     * points. */
    private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) {
        if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left) {
            dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
        } else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right) {
            dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
        }
        if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top) {
            dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
        } else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom) {
            dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
        }
    }

    /** Resets the dirty region when the motion event occurs. */
    private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {

        // The lastTouchX and lastTouchY were set when the ACTION_DOWN
        // motion event occurred.
        dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
        dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
    }
}
```

and I use FrameLayout to show in the app like this.

```
FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
drawView = new DrawView(this);
drawView.requestFocus();
preview.addView(drawView);
```

It is working fine. My question is how do I do validation for this. Let's say I throw a pop up saying customer hasn't signed yet. please advice.

Comment: Are there any rules for a signature being valid?

Comment: use this way this is work for me  if(eventX + eventY>0) true then user touch canvas if it is false customer hasn't signed  in onTouchEvent() method

Comment: @Luksprog yup....the sign area should not be empty.

Comment: @DixitPatel which way ya...?

Comment: @chinna_82 Can't you just set a flag whether or not the user started signing?

Comment: yes you are right use flag to identify signature is drawn or not & there is no any way to identify the signature is valid.